# WCF Delegation, Service couldn't access SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, wcf, active-directory, identity-delegation

I have the following infrastructure:

- Computer #1, Microsoft SQL Server 2008, started under System account. There is login `Master\MyLogin` (with Windows Authintification), server roles = `sysadm`, database role = `db_owner`.
- Computer # 2, WCF service on IIS 7.0. Application and site run under account `Master\IISLogin` (IISLogin@myDomain.ru)

Configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="CommonWindowsBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="40000000">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CommonBehavior" name="MyNameSpace.AdminService">
        <endpoint address="Windows" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CommonWindowsBinding" name="IAdminServiceWindows" contract="MyNameSpace.IAdminService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="WCFServer" />
            <userPrincipalName value="IISLogin@myDomain.ru"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CommonBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
        </clientCertificate>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="WCFServer" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyClassFullName, MyDllFullName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Service has method

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]
public bool HasRole(string roleName)
{
     //work with database
}
```

It uses EF 5.0 database first. Connection string

```
"Data Source=Computer1; Initial Catalog=myDB; Integrated Security=True; Multipleactiveresultsets=True; Persist Security Info=True;"
```

- Computer # 3, the client. It has the following config

  ```
  <configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
          <binding name="CommonWindowsBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
              openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
              transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
              hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
              maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="40000000">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                  maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                  enabled="false" />
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            </security>
          </binding>
       </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
      <endpoint  name="Megatec.MasterTourService.Contracts.IAdminServiceWindows"
          address="net.tcp://Computer2:5012/IISTest/AdminService.svc/Windows"
          behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior"
          binding="netTcpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="CommonWindowsBinding"
          contract="Megatec.MasterTourService.Contracts.IAdminService">
         <identity>
              <dns value="WCFServer" />
         </identity>
      </endpoint>        
  </client>
  <behaviors>         
    <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000"/>
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="WCFClient" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
            storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
             <serviceCertificate>
                 <defaultCertificate findValue="WCFServer" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                     x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                 <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" 
                                 revocationMode="NoCheck"
                                 trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"/>
              </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
  ```

Channel has the following credentials

```
channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
    System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;
channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential =
    System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

It falls with db error

> *Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\Anonymous'*

So, there is some problem with WCF delegation. When I tried to use simple `username/password` authentication, it worked fine - so, certificates and so on are fine.

I did Step 4 on [this instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650896.aspx), but it doesn't work.

Maybe something is wrong with my code or configs? How can I fix it?

**UPDATE**.

1. Tried (no result)

   [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)] => [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
2. Tried  (no result)
3. On the service side

   ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.ImpersonationLevel = Impersonation (not Delegation!)
4. When I tried to change identity for IIS pool from ApplicationPoolIdentity to IISLogin@myDomain.ru, the client on the computer 3 crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, Transport/TransportWithMessageCredential security mode doesn't support such work with client credentials and delegation. I've changed `CommonWindowsBinding` in the following way

Server

```
    <binding name="CommonWindowsBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="40000000">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Client

```
    <binding name="CommonWindowsBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="40000000">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
       <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your computer3 config try the following (in place of your current `<behaviors>...</behaviors>` block):

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <!--<windows allowNtlm="false" allowedImpersonationLevel="Delegation" />-->
        <windows allowNtlm="true" allowedImpersonationLevel="Delegation" />
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Edit you might also need to setup Active Directory record on Computer2 to allow credential delegation to Computer1 on "all types" (not just Kerberos)

Comment: NTLM doesn't support Delegation, as I know. Only Kerberos can.

Comment: @SirHally as mentioned in my Edit: remark, you need to setup AD to allow delegation on "all types" and then you can delegate using NTML, I use this exact way to allow my web service to delegate to Exchange using NTLM